# Rails Polymorphic Model for 1 Database Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design, architecture, polymorphism

I am working on a rails app for a charity who takes crowd-funded donations for **Families**, **Fundraisers**, and for the **charity** itself. Right now donations are setup to belong to Families & Fundraisers using Polymorphism, but I'm not sure how to take money for the charity.

Should I make a model for donations to the charity? That feels like bad architecture to me because it will be a single database record.

What is the best way to take donations for the charity?

Here is my donation model:

```
#app/models/donation.rb
class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_token
  belongs_to :family, via: :recipient
  belongs_to :fundraiser, via: :recipient
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

in your migration you should do something like

```
class Donations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :donations do |t|
      ...
      t.integer :something_id # this is the record id of something 
      t.string :something_type # this is the model name like family or fundraiser

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now in your model

```
class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :something, polymorphic: true
end

# repeat this in all the models that can use this polymorphic association 
class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :donations, as: :something
end
```

I hope that this has helped.

Happy Hacking

Comment: yes, I know that. I've already done that. But now I need to have controllers that belong to a charity. I'm asking how to setup Donations for the charity. Should make a model that only has 1 record (Charity)? That seems bad to me.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is `Donations.last.something` this returns a family or fundraiser

Comment: No, I'm trying to decide if I should make a charity model or if there is a better way to collect donations that do NOT go to a family or a fundraiser, but directly to the charity.